# Why should the function which is called for 'onClick' here in this code snippet bellow should be called inside another arrow function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Here is the code snippet...

```
const CountClicks = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    return(
        <div>
            <p>You clicked {count} times.</p>        
            <button onClick={() => {setCount(count + 1)}}>
                Click me
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I tried `<button onClick={setCount(count + 1)}>` which led to the following errors being displayed:

> Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value assigned to `onClick` must be a **function**.

`onClick={setCount(count + 1)}` will call `setCount` **immediately** and assign its return value as the function to call when the element is clicked.

Since it doesn't return a function, nothing would happen if it was clicked.

However, it never gets that far because calling `setCount` changes the state and triggers a rerender … which calls `setCount` and triggers a rerender which … ∞

Comment: Is there a way to insert a code block directly in the template without it being wrapped in a function like OP wanted ? (I don't know much of react)

Comment: @Seblor — You have to create the function at some point. You could do it outside the JSX part and store it in a variable.

Comment: I see. I'm used to work with VueJS where there can be either a function or a statement directly in the template. Thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 0):

What `onClick` expects is a function. Using Anonymous Closure fat arrow function (`() => {setCount(count + 1)}`) you are passing a function as prop. even passing function as prop like `onClick={setCount}` you are passing a function. But if you use `onClick={setCount(count + 1)}`, what you actually are doing is passing the return value of `setCount` function on every render. `onClick` is event handler that expects a function.